# How to fix the error "Required Attributes birthday" in AWS Cognito with Google OAuth2.0?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0

I'm working on my React Native project with AWS amplify and I want to implement Oauth2.0 into my authentication process(first time using Oauth2.0) I followed to docs on aws-amplify about OAuth2.0 and I believe I set it up correctly but I'm always receiving the error `OAuth - Error handling auth response. [Error: attributes+required%3A+%5Bbirthdate%5D]` and I have no idea how to fix it, here are my current settings for aws:

Authorized scopes: `profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read openid`

Attribute Mapping:

[image]

App Client:

[image]

setting on the Google API Consent Screen:

[image]

CAn anyone help me fix this because I have no idea what is wrong?

Comment: please update with the amplify request you are sending